# 16:9 format with resizing

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm looking for a way how I can change an image in a 16:9 format. I want to create a little game with a 16:9 ratio. I have a picture, buttons and ellipses, this picture should get a 16:9 format and all  other stuff. Initially it is intended to query the user's screen and thus adjust the size of the image and the other to the screen in a 16:9 ratio.
As soon as the size of the screen changes, the size of the pictures and the other stuff should also change, always in a 16:9 ratio.

Comment: So then why not just save that image in a 16:9 ratio? Then it's just a matter of resizing it for the screen.

Comment: Btw,  maybe CSS could be usefull for that? Example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You could try scaling the pictures by a defined amount to maintain scale with the canvas as you change the aspect ratio.

Example:

```
let image = loadImage("_____.png");
// When renderering the image scale by some amount.

push();
scale(width * scaleFactor);
image(image, x, y, w, h);
pop();
```